# Data from REST API is not fetching by useReducer in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

when I try to load the data from my local machine by useReducer, it is working well. But if I try to load data from rest API data is not loaded, state is empty:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        item: products, //products is coming from products.js file which is an array
        totalAmount: 0,
        totalItem: 0,
    });


    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "GET_TOTAL" });
    }, [state.item]);
```

in case of rest api:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getProducts = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(
                "https://api.com"
            );

            setProducts(res.data);
        };
        getProducts();
    }, []);

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
            item: products, //products is coming from rest api
            totalAmount: 0,
            totalItem: 0,
        });
    
    
        useEffect(() => {
            dispatch({ type: "GET_TOTAL" });
        }, [state.item]);

console.log(state);
```

reducer.js:

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {

    if (action.type === "GET_TOTAL") {
        let { totalItem, totalAmount } = state.item.reduce(
            (accum, curVal) => {
                let { price, quantity } = curVal;

                let updatedTotalAmount = price * quantity;
                accum.totalAmount += updatedTotalAmount;

                accum.totalItem += quantity;
                return accum;
            },
            {
                totalItem: 0,
                totalAmount: 0,
            }
        );

        return { ...state, totalItem, totalAmount };
    }
    return state;
};
```

console:

[image: console]

why is this happening? It is working for local data but not working for remote data.

Comment: Can you show your code for reducer function? 
Also here `dispatch({ type: "GET_TOTAL" });`  along  with type you need to add `payload` key, which will be your data coming from api.

Comment: I believe ```dispatch({ type: "GET_TOTAL" });``` should be in the first ```useEffect```, because ```state.items``` is initialized only in first render.

Comment: I have edited the post including reducer

Comment: If it's empty it's because the initial value of products is an empty array, so the first time it will come to the call of useReducer the value will initialize at empty array, you should fill it after receiving the data.

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier how can I fill this after receiving the data?

Comment: You can create an action inside your reducer to fill it, something like "INIT" or "ADD_ITEMS" with your products inside the payload. With this way you can avoid the use of the state products and you will replace `setProducts` by `dispatch({ type: "ADD_ITEMS", payload: products });`

Comment: I don't understand, it would be better you write the code

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier thanks, got your point